# How to save binary of multi-dimensional matrix in Matlab and load it to as a C++ struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, bin

I have a multi-dimensional matrix in **Matlab**, I save it as a binary file like this:

```
mat = reshape(1:90, 9,5,2);
fileName = 'mat.bin';
fid = fopen(fileName, 'w');
fwrite(fid, mat, 'int32');
fclose(fid);
```

In **C++** I load it like this:

```
struct Mat {
    int32_t arr[9][5][2];
};

std:ifstream input("mat.bin");
Mat* m = new Mat();
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m), sizeof(Mat));
input.close();
```

The problem is that the loaded data is not arranged the same way in memory 
for instance:

Accessing `arr[1][1][1]` will yield the value of the Matlab's array of indices `mat(5,2,1)`

(considering of course that Matlab's indices start at 1)

How can I arrange the matrix (and any other multi-dimensional matrix) before writing it to a binary file, in a way that `arr[i][j][k]` will be the same as `mat(i+1, j+1, k+1)`?

EDIT :

> Current solution
>   For the 2-D case, Transpose of matrix solves it.
>
> For x-D I found that I can change the order of vectors like this
>   `permute(mat, [D D-1 D-2 ... 1])` so it's like spreading the vectors
>   (which matches how memory is mapped in C++) I still look for a more
>   general code that doesn't have to write a vector of dimensions (which
>   sometimes change)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `shiftdim` in MATLAB before the file write, to structure the data in the way your C++ read expects?

Comment: @Wolfie I can use any Matlab function / C++ action (e.g define a different struct, load in a different ordering, etc.) to transfer the data.

Comment: I wasn't asking if you physically *could* use `shiftdim`, I was asking if it addressed your problem...

Comment: @Wolfie - I didn't find a way to achieve this with `shiftdim`, only `permute` which also shifts/permutes **dimensions** (the name is quite confusing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to store arrays as plain 1D arrays and fixing how you access it. Your `mat[5][2][1]` is equivalent to `mat[1 + 2*2 + 5*10]`. When moving on to dynamic memory allocation, creating an array that is indexed as `mat[5][2][1]` implies allocating an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of data. This involves a huge overhead in memory allocation (which is quite expensive) and causes memory fragmentation and poor cache performance. Instead, allocating a single plain array that can hold the data, and computing the linear index from your 3 indices is quite simple and cheap.

This is a trivial implementation (without any form of checking) for a dynamically allocated 3D array:

```cpp
struct Mat {
   using value_type = int32_t;
   std::vector<value_type> data;
   int size[3] = {0, 0, 0};
   Mat(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
      size[0] = s1; size[1] = s2; size[2] = s3;
      data.resize(s1 * s2 * s3);
   }
   value_type operator()(int i, int j, int k) {
      return data[(k * size[1] + j) * size[0] + i];
   }
};
```

Of course, you could make it into a `class` with appropriate data hiding, etc. Or you could just use one of the many libraries that exist that implement such arrays. There's an overloaded operator `()` for indexing: `m(5,2,1)` is translated to the appropriate indexing into the 1D array `m.data`. (I didn't bother here to return the indexed element by reference, but that would of course make more sense).

---

Here's a complete program to test it. With the input data being integers 1:90 in column-major storage order, in MATLAB I see this:

```matlab
>> mat(6,3,2)
ans =  69
```

The C++ program outputs this:

```
m(5,2,1) = 69
```

Source code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Mat {
   using value_type = int32_t;
   std::vector<value_type> data;
   int size[3] = {0, 0, 0};
   Mat(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
      size[0] = s1; size[1] = s2; size[2] = s3;
      data.resize(s1 * s2 * s3);
   }
   value_type operator()(int i, int j, int k) {
      return data[(k * size[1] + j) * size[0] + i];
   }
};

int main() {
   std::ifstream input("mat.bin");
   Mat m(9, 5, 2);
   input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m.data.data()), m.data.size() * sizeof(Mat::value_type));
   input.close();
   std::cout << "m(5,2,1) = " << m(5,2,1) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In this case the dimensions of the matrix are statically set - so the memory layout of the matrix is continuous (same as 1-D array).It is much more effective for **dynamically size allocated** matrices.

Comment: @joepol: yes, the efficiency problems happen with dynamically allocated arrays. I think it’s best to get used to linear indexing from the start, it prevents the many, many cases of `vector<vector<double>>` that I’ve seen on here. But more to the point of your question, this harmonizes indexing order in your C++ program to that of MATLAB without having to reorder data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `matC = permute(mat, ndims(mat):-1:1)`, before saving from MATLAB:

`permute(mat, ndims(mat):-1:1)`, changes dimensions from (9,5,2) to (2,5,9) in your example.

It's basically your solution but replacing `permute(mat, [D D-1 D-2 ... 1])` with `ndims(mat):-1:1`.

---

MATLAB code sample:

```matlab
mat = ones(9,5,2);

% Fill some data for testing:
mat(:, :, 1) = meshgrid(1:5, 1:9);
mat(:, :, 2) = meshgrid(101:105, 101:109);

matC = permute(mat, ndims(mat):-1:1);

fileName = 'mat.bin';
fid = fopen(fileName, 'w');
fwrite(fid, matC, 'int32');
fclose(fid);
```

---

C++ code sample:

```c++
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    struct Mat {
        int32_t arr[9][5][2];
    };

    std::ifstream input("mat.bin", std::ios_base::binary);
    Mat* m = new Mat();
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m), sizeof(Mat));
    input.close();

    delete m;    

    return 0;
}
```

Testing sample: 
In C++: `m->arr[3][4][1] = 105`
In MATLAB: `mat(4,5,2) = 105`

Comment: `ndims(mat):-1:1` - exactly what was missing. For a robust testing I would assign a different value for each cell.